# Recording raw RGB video format using picamera2

Tags: picamera

I am trying to record raw RGB video format using picamera2 and Raspberry Pi-4b, for the sake of imagining in the context of biological research. Basically, trying to avoid any compression, etc. during imaging and recording, because the point is to detect the full-rage of biological signal, instead of human vision.

What would be a good way of doing that? Either recording raw RGB to begin with, or record .raw and later convert to raw RGB would be fine. Willing to try both and see which one would work better.

Below is the code that I wrote using ChatGPT. Doesn't give error, but the output is scrambled.

#sensor format: 1296x972-SGBRG10_1X10 - Selected unicam format: #1296x972-pGAA

import numpy as np
import cv2

import numpy as np

def unpack_10bit_to_16bit(bayer_data, frame_dimensions):
"""
Unpacks 10-bit packed Bayer data into a 16-bit numpy array.
Assumes the input data is packed as 4 pixels in 5 bytes.
This version adjusts to handle data lengths that do not match exactly,
useful for processing the last frame of a video or imperfect data.
"""
total_pixels = frame_dimensions[0] * frame_dimensions[1]
packed_bytes = total_pixels * 10 // 8

```
# Adjust to allow processing of data that's shorter than expected
actual_packed_bytes = min(len(bayer_data), packed_bytes)

bayer_data = np.frombuffer(bayer_data[:actual_packed_bytes], dtype=np.uint8)
unpacked_data = np.zeros(total_pixels, dtype=np.uint16)

# Calculate how many complete groups of 4 pixels are present
complete_groups = actual_packed_bytes // 5
for i in range(complete_groups):
    byte_index = i * 5
    unpacked_data[i*4] = ((bayer_data[byte_index] << 2) | (bayer_data[byte_index + 1] >> 6)) & 0x03FF
    unpacked_data[i*4 + 1] = (((bayer_data[byte_index + 1] & 0x3F) << 4) | (bayer_data[byte_index + 2] >> 4)) & 0x03FF
    unpacked_data[i*4 + 2] = (((bayer_data[byte_index + 2] & 0x0F) << 6) | (bayer_data[byte_index + 3] >> 2)) & 0x03FF
    unpacked_data[i*4 + 3] = (((bayer_data[byte_index + 3] & 0x03) << 8) | bayer_data[byte_index + 4]) & 0x03FF

return unpacked_data.reshape(frame_dimensions)
```

def demosaic_bayer_to_rgb(bayer_frame, pattern='GBRG'):
"""
A simple nearest-neighbor demosaicing algorithm for demonstration.
Adjusted for the GBRG pattern (interpreted from SGBRG10).
"""
height, width = bayer_frame.shape
rgb_frame = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint16)

```
# Green channel (placed at both red and blue positions for GBRG)
rgb_frame[0::2, 0::2, 1] = bayer_frame[0::2, 0::2]  # Green pixels on blue rows
rgb_frame[1::2, 1::2, 1] = bayer_frame[1::2, 1::2]  # Green pixels on red rows

# Blue channel
rgb_frame[0::2, 1::2, 2] = bayer_frame[0::2, 1::2]  # Blue pixels

# Red channel
rgb_frame[1::2, 0::2, 0] = bayer_frame[1::2, 0::2]  # Red pixels

return rgb_frame
```

def convert_raw_to_rgb_video(raw_file_path, output_video_path, frame_dimensions, frame_rate=15, pattern='GBRG'):
frame_size = frame_dimensions[0] * frame_dimensions[1] * 10 // 8

```
with open(raw_file_path, 'rb') as raw_file:
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_video_path, fourcc, frame_rate, (frame_dimensions[1], frame_dimensions[0]), isColor=True)
    
    while True:
        raw_frame_data = raw_file.read(frame_size)
        if not raw_frame_data:
            break
        
        # Unpack the raw frame data
        unpacked_data = unpack_10bit_to_16bit(raw_frame_data, frame_dimensions)
        
        # Convert the unpacked data to RGB
        rgb_frame = demosaic_bayer_to_rgb(unpacked_data, pattern)
        
        # Convert the 16-bit data to 8-bit for video writing
        rgb_frame_8bit = np.clip(rgb_frame / 4, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
        
        # Write the frame to the output video
        out.write(rgb_frame_8bit)
    
    out.release()  # Make sure to release the video writer
```

## Example usage

convert_raw_to_rgb_video(
'test.raw',
'test.mp4',
(1024, 1024),
15,
'GBRG')

Comment: `Willing to try both and see which one would work better.` . . why are you asking, instead of trying?